# Get max of two entries query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

**Query:**

```
select machinename, StatusCode, size
from machine where MachineID In( '33','22') and StatusCode = 166 
ORDER BY size DESC
```

**Result:**

```
machinename  StatusCode  size
-----------  ----------  ----
test1        166         50
test1        166         25
test2        166         75
test2        166         48
```

**Requirement:**

I need to display only one entry for each machine.
I have to do this by taking the max size value between the two entries as shown above.
like for test1 i have two sizes 50 and 25 I have to show the row which has 50 and ignore row which has 25.

Thanks

**Desired Result:**

```
machinename  StatusCode  size
-----------  ----------  ----
test1        166         50
test2        166         75
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I don't understand what you mean by "where the size is greater than the other."

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by where the size is greater than the other.  Are you just looking for the max size for that machine name?

Comment: eg for machine test1, i have two sizes 50 and 25 so i want to display only the row with size 50 and not 25. let me know if i need to explain mare

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work, but you won't be able to order by starttime

```
select machinename, StatusCode, max(size) as size
from machine where MachineID In( '33','22') and StatusCode = 166 
group by machinename, StatusCode
order by max(size) DESC
```

Comment: +1 This is best for updated query. Except you have missed a DESC.

Comment: Actually it would be possible to `ORDER BY MAX(StartTime)`.

Comment: Yes, but that wouldn't tie to the same record that had the max(size), so all it would really tell you is when the last time this machine had a test

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to order by StartTime you would have to use `ROW_NUMBER` so that you could select the starttime field:

```
SELECT machinename, StatusCode, size
FROM (
    SELECT
        machinename,
        StatusCode,
        StartTime
        size,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MachineID ORDER BY size DESC) AS rn
    FROM machine
    WHERE MachineID IN ('33','22')
    AND StatusCode = 166 
) T1
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY StartTime DESC
```

But if you want to order by size, it's easier:

```
SELECT machinename, StatusCode, MAX(size) AS size
FROM machine
WHERE MachineID IN ('33','22') AND StatusCode = 166 
GROUP BY MachineID
ORDER BY MAX(size) DESC
```

Comment: sorry but the server went down. will test and check correct answer

Answer (score 2):

Use a windowing function to generate ids to partition on your key and then order by largest to smallest. This will generate 1-N for each partition where 1 will correspond to the largest value from the ORDER BY. We then filter for the largest one.

```
; WITH MACHINES AS
(
select machinename, StatusCode, size
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY machinename ORDER BY size DESC) AS RN
from machine where MachineID In( '33','22') and StatusCode = 166 

)
SELECT
select machinename, StatusCode, size
FROM MACHINES M
WHERE M.rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select machinename, StatusCode, size
from machine a
where MachineID In( '33','22') and StatusCode = 166 
and size = (select max(size) 
from machine b
where MachineID In( '33','22') and StatusCode = 166 
and a.machinename = b.machinename)
ORDER BY StartTime DESC
```

HTH.

Comment: sorry but the server went down. will test and check correct answer